# Message hash verifier with expiry

Tags: algorithm, hash

I have 2 servers/programs.

I want to hash some information from the first server and send it to the second one.

The second one should verify the hash if it is correct and return the information.

So I can verify the information is secure.

For example:

user with id = 26 | hash = ea135amemf

I send the id and hash to the second server - it checks if the hash is matched and returns user data (birthdate, username, whatever).

On both sides i have some algorithm for the hash (the same one)

That works OK, but...

I want to integrate a time limit into the hash with the logic below:

I would like to have some time limit, for example 10 seconds.

If I generate the hash from the first server at **12:50:55** - and send the request to the 2nd at **12:51:05** the hash will match. If I send the hash after **12:51:05** the hash would be invalid.

I don't want to store the hash in the database, or hash or send the timestamp with the request.

My point is that the request should be valid for 10 seconds (or whatever limit I want - 20 seconds, 1minute or so).

I wonder if there is a way to check the hash only with the provided id and hash with some formula.

Note: The timezones on both servers are the same.

That way the hash for the resource will be different if I generate it at 13:00:00, 13:30:00, 15:00:00.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: In JWTs (Javascript Web Tokens) the timestamp is included in the content that is transmitted (the payload) and in the content that is hashed. I don't think there is a way to do this without sending the timestamp, or some representation of the timestamp, with the request.

Comment: Thanks, i want to disable if someone sniff the post request and get the timestamp and hash if he send the post request after an hour i want to reject it

Comment: You can reject that by comparing the timestamp to the current time and if it is greater than 1 hour, reject it. Including the timestamp in the content to be hashed prevents a replay attack like that if the hashing algorithm is secret and cannot be discovered. But it's more secure to use a cryptographic signature, that way you are not relying on security through obscurity. Alternatively you can use authenticated requests, but that just pushes the problem up to the authentication layer.

Comment: So if i hash the content +  timestamp i should send the timestamp with the request as a separate data (hash=..., timestamp=...) because there is no way to see what timestamp the reqeust is sent. And then check both timestamp and hash (with timestamp in it alsoe). Is this a good way to go